# php : How to check a field have blank/empty/NULL value?

Tags: php, validation

I want to display an error when a variable have a BLANK value or EMPTY or NULL value. for example variable is shown below:

```
 $mo = strtotime($_POST['MondayOpen']);
```

and
    `var_dump($_POST['MondayOpen'])` returns `string(0) "".`

Now I go with below approach

1. First want to find which type of variable `$mo` is ?(string or
   integer or other)
2. Which function is better to find that `$mo` having no value.

I conduct a test with `$mo` and got these results

```
is_int($mo);//--Return nothing
is_string($mo); //--Return bool(false) 
var_dump($mo);  //--Return bool(true)                   
var_dump(empty($mo));//--Return bool(true) 
var_dump($mo==NULL);//--Return bool(true) 
var_dump($mo=='');//--Return nothing
```

Please suggest an optimum and right approach to check the variable integrity

Comment: As a side note, you are using `==` which tests for equality, such as `1 == '1'` which would evaluate to `true`. But when you use `===` it tests if the types are equal. In my example `1 === '1'` will return false, since `int` is not a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doing strtotime will return false if it cannot convert to a time stamp.

```
$mo = strtotime($_POST['MondayOpen']);
if ($mo !== false)
{
//valid date was passed in  and $mo is type int
}
else
{
//invalid date let the user know
}
```

Answer (score 4):

var_dump outputs variables for debugging purposes, it is not used to check the value in a normal code. PHP is loosely typed, most of the time it does not matter if your variable is a string or an int although you can cast it if you need to make sure it is one, or use the is_ functions to check.

To test if something is empty:

```
if ( empty( $mo ) ) {
  // error
}
```

empty() returns true if a variable is 0, null, false or an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

PHP offers a function [**`isset`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if a variable is not `NULL` and [**`empty`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if a variable is empty.

To return the type, you can use the PHP function [**`gettype`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)

```
if (!isset($mo) || is_empty($mo)) {
 // $mo is either NULL or empty.
 // display error message
 }
```

Comment: if (!isset($mo) || empty($mo)) is redundant.
if (empty($mo)) has the same behavior.

Comment: Problem with "empty($var)" function is that consider $var="0" as ... empty. Which is obviously not ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check its type using:

```
gettype($mo);
```

but **null** and **empty** are different things, you can check with these functions:

```
if (empty($mo))
{
  // it is empty
}

if (is_null($mo))
{
  // it is null
}
```

Another way to check if variable has been set is to use the **isset** construct.

```
if (isset($mo))
{
  // variable has been set
}
```