# MYSQL query statement for empty field

Tags: php, mysql, database

My database contains data as per the sample below. I would like to select the red highlighted row. Tried this query but doesn't display the row that I wanted. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxxx");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row['imageurl'] == 0){
echo $row['email'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Code above will return 'abc@abc.com'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE imageurl IS NULL
```

If you want all results and test for `NULL` in PHP, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201452/in-php-how-to-check-a-field-have-blank-empty-null-value).

Answer (score 1):

Any reason on not doing it from query level?

`"SELECT * From tablename where length(imageurl) = 0 or imageurl is null"`

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
if($row['imageurl'] == 0){
```

to :

```
if(empty($row['imageurl']) == true){
```

This will check if the imageurl is an empty string or null, as you want .

Answer (score 0):

Probably the following statement solves your task:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE imageurl IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($row['imageurl'])){
echo $row['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field is just empty (and not NULL) try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE length(imageurl) = 0
```