# How to set my value only after checking my checkbox?

Tags: php, checkbox

I have created one form with dynamically created fields. and i have a one check box with unique ID . when user selects that check box then only those two fields are visible ("name and age"). and if user uncheck the select box then those fields are hiding . here is the code

```
 <style>
      .selectContainer{
       display:none;
        }
      input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .selectContainer {
        display:block;
        }


</style>
```

And The HTML code Is:

```
                  <label for="name">Any Accompanying Person ?:</label>

            <input  type="checkbox" name="person" id="person" >Yes



            <div class="selectContainer">

            <br>



            <label>Person Details</label>
            <p>



             <div style="padding-left:70px;"> 
            <input type="button" value="Add Person" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Remove Person" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /> 
            </div>
            </p>
            <table style="padding-left:50px;" id="dataTable" class="form" border="1"  >
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <p>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
            <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" size="20" name="name[]" id="name"   >
            </td>
            <td>
            <label>Age</label>
            <input type="text" size="20" name="age[]" id="age"  >
            </td>

            </p>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>

            </div>
                          <h3>Choose Your Payment Option</h3>
        <h1>

        <div style="padding-left:150px;">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="visa" required value="1" >VISA/MASTER CARD:<br />
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="cheque"> CHEQUE/DEMAND DRAFT<br />
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="neft">NEFT<br /><br/>

        </div>
        <label></label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"><br />
```

And the php Code is:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    $intIncrement = 0;
    for($l=0; $l < count($name); $l++)
    {
    if ($age[$l]>=12)
    {
    $intIncrement++;
    }


    $user_name="name";

    $user_id=123;


    $qry="INSERT INTO Accomp_Person (name,age,ref_id, ref_name)

    VALUES ('$name[$l]','$age[$l]', '$user_id','$user_name')";
```

Problem:
 i am storing name and age of the Accompanying Person .if user checks the check box and add the  name and age then its storing in database successfully but the problem is when user came and simply check and  then after uncheck the check box  (Any Accompanying Person?) then the empty value is storing in database . how to avoid this . i want store those value only check box(Accompanying Person?) is checked. Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please user this code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$checkBox = $_POST['chk'];

$intIncrement = 0;
for($l=0; $l < count($name); $l++)
{
if ($age[$l]>=12)
{
$intIncrement++;
}

$user_name="name";

$user_id=123;
if(isset($checkBox[$l])){
$qry="INSERT INTO Accomp_Person (name,age,ref_id, ref_name)

VALUES ('$name[$l]','$age[$l]', '$user_id','$user_name')";
}

}
```

Comment: not that check box. This is the check box  (<label for="name">Any Accompanying Person ?:</label>

            <input  type="checkbox" name="person" id="person" >Yes).

Answer (score 0):

Before storing the value of `$name` and `$age` to database, check if they have valid non-empty values.

You can check for empty values in the following way -

```
if (!isset($name) || empty($name)) {
  // $name is either NULL or empty.
  // display error message
}
```

Comment: how to check weather my values are empty or not ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201452/php-how-to-check-a-field-have-blank-empty-null-value

Answer (score 0):

set default value in your database for  name and age.
check if check box is checked.
And disable age and name if check box not checked.
Form does not post disable inputs. so it will not save with empty

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
          $firstNameErr = "Name is required";
          $valid = false; //false
       }
       else {
          $name= test_input($_POST["name"]);
       }
       if (empty($_POST['age'])) {
          $ageErr= "Age is required";
          $valid = false;
       }
       else {
          $age= test_input($_POST["age"]);
       }
 if($valid){
  // do the insert here
  }
```

Comment: if value is set then all so not storing .

Answer (score 0):

While you'll still need to verify server-side, in PHP, this approach runs in the front-end to disable each of the `<input>` elements in the same row as the checkbox. A disabled element is not considered 'successful,' and therefore is not submitted to the server:

> A *successful control* is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its [control name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#control-name) paired with its [current value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#current-value) as part of the submitted [form data set](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#form-data-set). A successful control must be defined within a [FORM](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM) element and must have a [control name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#control-name).
>
> However:
>
> - Controls that are [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#disabled) cannot be successful.

<sub>"[Successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)," [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/) as accessed at 13:21 (GMT), 19/01/2015.</sub>

```js
function toggleRowInputs() {
  // caching a reference to the changed checkbox element:
  var checkbox = this,
      // the starting point for the (following) while loop:
    row = checkbox;
  
  // while the tagName of the 'row' variable is neither 'tr' nor 'body':
  while (row.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr' && row.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
    // row is changed to the current node's parentNode and we run again:
    row = row.parentNode;
  }

  // if the checkbox was found inside of a <tr> element:
  if (row.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr') {
    // we find all the <input> elements of that row, and use filter()
    // to keep only those elements that are not of type="checkbox":
    var inputs = Array.prototype.filter.call(row.querySelectorAll('input'), function(input) {
      if (input.type !== 'checkbox') {
        return input;
      }
    });
    
    // iterating over those found inputs:
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      // if the checkbox is checked we enable (disabled = false) the input,
      // otherwise if it's unchecked we disable (disabled = true) the input:
      input.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
    });
  }

}


// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the array-like NodeList
// returned by document.querySelectorAll() (which uses CSS syntax to find
// the <input> elements of type="checkbox":
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'), function(checkbox) {
  // adding an event-listener for the 'change' event to each of those
  // <input> elements, which executes the named function:
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', toggleRowInputs);
});
```

```css
input[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<table style="padding-left:50px;" id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="name[]" id="name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="age[]" id="age" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I've slightly changed your HTML, removing the needless `<p>` tags that originally surrounded some of the `<td>` elements, since the *only* valid children of a `<tr>` element is a `<td>` or a `<th>`, if you want a paragraph then it has to go *inside of* either of those elements.

References:

- HTML:

  - [Forms in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html).
  - "[Successful Controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)."
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
  - [`while (...) {...}` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Answer (score 0):

If you want Javascript to play some role, First thing you should do is to put a callback when checkbox is clicked. Thereafter you can check for existence of both Name and Age data.If both values exists, then only call addRow(). Here is simple prototype

```
<input type='checkbox' id='chk' onclick='check();'/>
<input type='text' id='name' />
<input type='text' id='age' '/>
```

And javascript snippet as:

```
function check(){
if(document.getElementById('chk').checked){
    var name= document.getElementById('name').value;
    var age=document.getElementById('age').value;
    if(name && age){
        //Only when both name and age, then addRow function call
    }
}
}
```

Hope you can take it from here!